# How can I install a specific version of Mesa?

Tags: apt, mesa

I need to install mesa 20.x for Unity3D. Using ubuntu 20.04.

I tried the two ppas (ppa:kisak/kisak-mesa and oxxx) but there version is more recent than ubuntu. How can I do this?

see bug report https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/linux-editor-crashes-at-assert-fail-base-dot-cold-when-opening-a-project

I tried `sudo apt-get install -f libgl1-mesa-dev=20.0.4-2ubuntu1`  
but I get the following message:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libgl1-mesa-dev : Depends: libgl-dev but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: libglvnd-dev but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

But libglvnd-dev is already installed

```
libglvnd-dev is already the newest version (1.3.2-1~ubuntu0.20.04.1).
```

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: I'm using 20.04 at the moment.